# EF 6 Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0)

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am getting the following error when I try to save changes made to a context for two of my entities.

> Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected
>   number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since
>   entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.

Based on other solutions, I don't really believe this to be a concurrency issue, since am developing a single user environment, and am supplying all mandatory fields. I can't capture my query from profiler, since I am using a SQL Azure database.

Comment: Are you sure that your table doesn't have a timestamp column?

Comment: no...this table don't have timestamp column

Answer (score 0):

I found out that had following index on my table :

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Item_Barcode] ON [dbo].[Item]
(
    [BarCodeID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
GO
```

But my BarcodeID field is declared as nullable in table. So once I try to add another record with blank BarcodeID or duplicate value, it will throw above error. Since I used the option **IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON**, I was hoping to bypass any error.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186869.aspx is states below :

> ON :
>   A warning message will occur when duplicate key values are inserted into a unique index. Only the rows violating the uniqueness constraint will fail.
>
> OFF :
>   An error message will occur when duplicate key values are inserted into a unique index. The entire INSERT operation will be rolled back.

So the work around would to turn this option OFF

Comment: you... posted the question and answered it all within a minute of initial question posting?  Did you mean for this to be an edit to the question?

Comment: @Kritner, I shared this as knowledge to assist others. Above answer does work for me. But am open for better solutions.